# Use index of nominal values instead of a string value

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures, c++17

I am working on real-time systems that receive discrete values in text format (from text file, or buffer). I need to collect statistics and do other numeric processing on these values and to speed things up I was thinking about using an integer (for example the index) instead of a `std::string`.

```
Allowed Values:
Black, Red, Green
After transformation:
0,1,2 (respectively)
```

I also want to control invalid values, for example `yellow` will be not valid, since it is not an allowed value.

So at any time `t`, I receive the value and need to parse it to its index, and then use it. CAVEAT: latency is really important, and I need it to be as fast as I can.

Which would be a proper high-performant way to implement this?

Comment: I would go with a standard approch using io streams and see if i meet the timing requirements. If you read from HDD or even SSD, you will probably be bound by IO.

Comment: I can get then from other sources than file system, and at high arrival rate.
But I am more interested in how to map the string to int. std::map seem overkill, and I was wandering if there is any other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If speed is important, then lookup tables are always a fast solution. And C++ offers Associative Containers.

A map is an appropriate solution.

See the following example:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>


using KeyType = std::string;
using LookUpValue = int;
using LookUpTable = std::map<KeyType,LookUpValue>;

LookUpTable lookUpTable {{"Black",1}, {"Red",2}, {"Green",3}};

constexpr LookUpValue InvalidInput{0};

inline LookUpValue convertTextToKey(const std::string& text)
{
    return (lookUpTable.end()==lookUpTable.find(text)) ? InvalidInput : lookUpTable[text];
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << convertTextToKey("Nonsense") << ' ' << convertTextToKey("Black") << ' '  
              << convertTextToKey("Red") << ' ' << convertTextToKey("Green") << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```